# ExcelのPHONETIC関数に相当する機能はありますか

Tags: emeditor

CSVセル選択モードで、あるセルに「あるく」と入力してから「歩く」に変換して確定すると、そのセルには「歩く」が入力され、次のセルには「あるく」が入力されるようにしたいのですが、そのようなことはできますか。

（参考）
ふりがなを取り出す関数の使い方(PHONETIC関数):Excel関数
[http://www.eurus.dti.ne.jp/~yoneyama/Excel/kansu/phonetic.html](http://www.eurus.dti.ne.jp/%7Eyoneyama/Excel/kansu/phonetic.html)